Pokémon Go stuck on specific location no matter where I am
After the newest update this bug started happening to me. I use my iPad to play Pokémon Go and use my phone as a hotspot.
For a year now nothing ever happened until last week when I went to the mall. Now every time I use my phone's hotspot to play Pokémon Go, I'm always located at that mall in-game, even when I am some where else. This also happens when I'm using the Wi-Fi of my house or somewhere else, and I can even catch and spin the PokéStop at the mall without being there.
Does anyone know what could be causing this?
I have tried activating and deactivating Airplane Mode on both devices, as well as rebooting. I'm not flying/GPS spoofing.

Welcome to Arqade! I think it could be your GPS getting confused. Have you updated your device recently?

There are times where my GPS wouldn't update my location for some people when they use Find My. Not sure how to fix this other then an update to the system.

Have you tried activating and deactivating airplane mode on both devices? Or simply reboot? Are you a legit player or are you a "flyer"?

am a legit player and i follow your help but it still not working for me

and also my phone is not ios so does that matter

@pokemongoplayer What kind of phone or iPad and system version are you using? Maybe that will help us figure out the issue.

Mine is a ipad air 3
